# Dynamically create Grouped UITableview sections in run time

Tags: iphone

I want to create grouped table as dynamically. My aim is creating sections as dynamically in run time in UITableview. In same time I will maintain all data in NSArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `-[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:]` as well as the other [insert/delete cell methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW53).

Comment: If you follow the link and then click on a method name, most of the methods have a "Related Sample Code" section that list several projects.